# A nice Application of Baire category Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f_n$ be continuous functions on a complete metric space $X$ such that 
$f_n(x)> 0$ for every $x \in X$. Let $A =\{x \in X \mid  \liminf f_n(x) =0 \}$. Prove that $A$ is a countable intersection of open sets in $X$
I know that we get to use Baire Category Theorem but I couldn't see the way. Can anyone see it?

Comment: A simple first idea: consider $A_n=\{ x : \text{ there exists a subsequence of } f_n(x) \text{ which is bounded above by } 1/n \}$. Try to show $A_n$ is open. I'd post this as an answer, but I haven't tried it (this is just the first idea that comes to mind).

Comment: @Ian : it's not clear to me that your $A_n$ is open. Take $X = [-1,1]$, $$f_n = \frac{1}{n} + nx\mathbb{1}_{[0, \frac{1}{n}]}(x) + \mathbb{1}_{[\frac{1}{n},1]}(x)$$ Then $A_n = [-1,0]$ (unless I made a mistake)

Comment: @Tryss I see. That's interesting. Perhaps another way to do it would be to consider the increasing sequence of functions $g_n(x)=\inf_{k \geq n} f_k(x)$. Then $A=\{ x : g_n(x) \to 0 \}$. My problem with this is that I don't think $g_n$ must be continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define

$$A_{n,k} = \left\{ x : f_n(x) <\frac{1}{k} \right\}$$

Each $A_{n,k}$ is open

Then the

$$B_{i,k} =\bigcup_{n>i} A_{n,k}$$

are open

And

$$A = \bigcap_{i,k} B_{i,k} $$

So $A$ is a countable intersection of open set

Indeed, $$x \in A \Leftrightarrow \forall k, \forall i, \exists n > i, f_n(x) < \frac{1}{k}$$

Comment: So, you don't use Baire category for this part.  But now you can prove that the set where $\liminf f_n = 0$ is not the set of rationals, since that is not a countable intersection of open sets (by Baire).

Comment: You don't need the Baire theorem. And X can be any space.